# How show simple icons with only css

Tags: html, css, unicode, fonts, icons

Is it possible to render icons (web safe, if they exist) to show an icon on a page without relying on specific fonts?

for example, if you have fontawesome font this will render an icon

```
a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f095";
}
```

So, my question is, is there a font type that is websafe which I can replace `\f095` code?

Comment: You may want to try these out: [&what; search for telephone](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/telephone).

Comment: UTF-8 Miscellaneous Symbols will help you on this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the Unicode Icons as an alternative. Just need to find out the HTML-Code for your specific Icon. Here is an example for the telephone Icon:

```html
<p>&#9743;</p>
```

Here is a link to a site which shows you the HTML-Code for each Unicode Icon:

https://unicode-table.com/en/

Answer (score 2):

If you can get the SVG's you need, you can create your own websafe icon font with https://icomoon.io/app/, or http://fontastic.me/, or http://fontello.com/, etc. Be sure to use Private Use Area (PUA) codes for the icons when exporting the font.